# method to do in place reversal of columns in a 2D array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

The problem is given a `2D array` write a method to reversal of columns. If possible, do it `in-place`
I have implemented and it works fine.but it is not `in-place`.It uses `auxillary storage`, is it possible to reverse columns of a 2D array without using matrix.

```
Here is my code:
public static int[][] reverseColumns(int[][] matrix){
        int rows=matrix.length;
        int cols=matrix[0].length;
        int temp=0;

        int[][] result= new int[rows][cols];

        for (int row=rows-1; row >=0; row--){
            for (int col=0;col<cols;col++){
                result[row][col]=matrix[temp][col];
            }
            temp++;
        }
        return result;
    }

  public static void print2DArray(int[][] result){
    for (int i=0; i < result.length;i++){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result[i]));

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[][] matrix = {
                {1,2,3,4},
                {5,6,7,8},
                {9,10,11,12},
                {13,14,15,16}
            int[][] result = reverseColumns(matrix);
    print2DArray(result);       
    System.out.println()
        };
```

output is :

```
[13, 14, 15, 16]
[9, 10, 11, 12]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is there a performance concern? You can print the column reversed if that is acceptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have followed the semantics of reversal of cols and rows as what you suggested:

```
   1 2 3                                     7 8 9
   4 5 6    _______column reversal_______    4 5 6 (vertically reversed) 
   7 8 9                                     1 2 3   



   1 2 3                                     3 2 1
   4 5 6    _______row reversal__________    6 5 4 (horizontally reversed) 
   7 8 9                                     9 8 7
```

It is possible to do both `in-place:`
for the `horizontal (row reversal)` it is straightforward. For the `vertical (col reversal)`, it needs some more understanding. Here the methods are; take an example `matrix` and try to follow the steps, you will understand

```
public static void reverseColumnsInPlace(int[][] matrix){
        for(int col = 0;col < matrix[0].length; col++){
            for(int row = 0; row < matrix.length/2; row++) {
                int temp = matrix[row][col];
                matrix[row][col] = matrix[matrix.length - row - 1][col];
                matrix[matrix.length - row - 1][col] = temp;
            }
    }
}

public static void reverseRowsInPlace(int[][] matrix){

    for(int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length / 2; col++) {
            int temp = matrix[row][col];
            matrix[row][col] = matrix[row][matrix[row].length - col - 1];
            matrix[row][matrix[row].length - col - 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to have a counter variable, say `row`,

then loop only to the middle of the array, and do

```
tmp = matrix[row];
matrix[row]=matrix[rows-1-row];
matrix[rows-1-row]=tmp;
```

where `rows` is the total count.

I'll let you figure out the type of `tmp`.

This is using just a constant auxiliary storage,
because `tmp` is just a reference (4 bytes in Java).

```
public static int[][] reverseColumns(int[][] matrix){
    int rows=matrix.length;
    int[] temp=null;
    for (int row=rows-1; row>=rows/2; row--){
        temp = matrix[row]; 
        matrix[row]=matrix[rows-1-row];
        matrix[rows-1-row] = temp;
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: my code reverses column of the array. please check again

Comment: To reverse the columns means that the last column becomes first, second last becomes second, etc. At least that's how I understand it. Your code reverses the elements within each column which means it reverses the rows. Check your input/output.

Comment: I imagined it as each column run down vertically, so reverse column means reverse this veritcal line, which is what my code does. but your suggestion tells me that reversing each array in the list of arrays is reversal of column, which I imagined as row...

Comment: Never mind, we're talking about the same thing. If that's your understanding your code is fine, you just need to use constant amount of auxiliary storage.

Comment: I have got "reversal of row by your above interpretation" without using auxillary storage working. but my question is about "reversal of columns" which I am having difficulty to code without auxillary

Comment: No, your initial question was about 'reversal of columns' in your interpretation which is 'reversal of rows' in mine. I think you cannot 'reverse the columns' (in my interpretation) that easily by just redirecting some references. Seems my initial note that you can do this for both rows and columns was wrong.

Answer (score -1):

This might help you with in-place exchanges:

```
private void swap(int[][] A, int row1, int col1, int row2, int col2) {
    int tmp = A[row1][col1];
    A[row1][col1] = A[row2][col2];
    A[row2][col2] = tmp;
}
```